# OpenGL exception when using glCreateVertexArrays

Tags: c++, opengl, exception

I was trying to compile this program through an `OpenGL API` for this `application` class:

```
#include "sb7.h"

using namespace sb7;
class my_application : public application
{
public:

    void startup()
    {
        render_program = compile_shaders();
        glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);    // <--
        glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
    } 
    void shutdown()
    {
        glDeleteProgram(render_program);
        glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);
        glDeleteProgram(render_program);
    }

    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        const GLfloat color[] = {  0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, color);

        glUseProgram(render_program);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);   
    }
private:
    GLuint render_program;
    GLuint vertex_array_object;
};

DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

However, I got the following exceptions:
[image]

It says that there is a problem with this line of code in the `startup()` function:

```
void startup()
{
    render_program = compile_shaders();
    glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vertex_array_object);    // <--
    glBindVertexArray(vertex_array_object);
}
```

I have tried using `glGenVertexArrays` but it still doesn't compile successfully.

Answer (score 0):

`glCreateVertexArrays` is a function from OpenGL 4.5. If it `NULL`, that most likely means that it isn't supported by the current OpenGL context in your program.

Are you sure that:

- you have an OpenGL 4.5 capable graphics card
- do you have a driver for your graphics card which supports OpenGL 4.5
- the framework you are using initializes an OpenGL 4.5 context?

Comment: Thanks! Actually glGenVertexArrays worked. Also the GLSL programs should be compiled with version 400.